# The subject and will change position to form questions

Tags: verbs, questions

I learned that we must change the subject to form questions using will.

But today while watching a movie I saw a question that they didn't change.

Example:

The subject and will change position to form questions:

1- You will be here?

2- Will you be here?

Are both right?
What is the rule?

Comment: There is no rule! Both are valid, but they have different meanings. The first one definitely implies disbelief. The second may or may not, depending on context.

Comment: @FeliniusRex is there any material to read about it? When should I use the first one or the second one?

Answer (score 1):

As Felinius mentioned, the first example conveys disbelief. This is common with sentences that become questions, such as "you ate earlier" becoming "you ate earlier?". Contrast this to "did you eat earlier", which is plain.

The form "Will you be here?" is the inversion of "you will be here", which is the indicative, and is a very very common, plain way to form questions.

However, "you will be here?" is a sentence with a question mark, so is often used to express disbelief or surprise, among other things.

Check out Wikipedia's article on Questions, which calls these [Polar Questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question#Polar_questions):

> Different languages may use different mechanisms to distinguish polar ("yes-no") questions from declarative statements (in addition to the question mark). English is one of a small number of languages which use word order. Another example is French

And the following section on [intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question#Intonation):

> In some languages, such as English, or Russian, a rising declarative is a sentence which is syntactically declarative but is understood as a question by the use of a rising intonation. For example, "You're not using this?"